# How to convert Vec<i32> to types::array::ArrayBase<Option<i32>> for rust-postgres?

Tags: postgresql, rust

```
let ids: Vec<i32> = get_ids(); //get_ids impl elsewhere
let stmt = db_conn.prepare(
    "SELECT id, name, created FROM person
    WHERE id = ANY( $1 )").unwrap();
let mut iter = stmt.query(
    [&ids]).unwrap();
```

This results in the error:

```
error: failed to find an implementation of trait postgres::types::ToSql for collections::vec::Vec<i32>
```

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres#type-correspondence), 
this means that I need to convert it to `types::array::ArrayBase<Option<i32>>`.

How do I do this?

---

My best attempt so far is:

```
let idOptions: Vec<Option<i32>> = ids.iter().map( |i| Some(i) ).collect();
let idsForDb: postgres::types::array::ArrayBase<Option<i32>> =
    postgres::types::array::ArrayBase::from_vec(idOptions, 0);
let mut iter = stmt.query(
    [&idsForDb]).unwrap();
```

Which results in:

```
error: expected core::iter::FromIterator<core::option::Option<&i32>>, but found core::iter::FromIterator<core::option::Option<i32>> (expected i32 but found &-ptr) [E0095]
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `Option<&i32>` ? (would be `Some(&i)` in `map`)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah `let idOptions: Vec<Option<&i32>> = ids.iter().map( |i| Some(i) ).collect();` works, but the thing is that I need to **get rid of** the `&`, not keep it, as otherwise I get a different error: `error: failed to find an implementation of trait postgres::types::ToSql for postgres::types::array::ArrayBase<core::option::Option<&i32>>`

Comment: You should really precise on *which line* the error occurs. the latter error occurs on the first line whether the former occurred on the last... something like `// <-- error here` would be invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

The trick lied in dereferencing the pointer within the closure function in map `|i| Some(*i)`:

```
let idOptions: Vec<Option<i32>> = ids.iter().map( |i| Some(*i) ).collect();
let idsForDb: postgres::types::array::ArrayBase<Option<i32>> =
    postgres::types::array::ArrayBase::from_vec(idOptions, 0);
let mut iter = stmt.query(
    [&idsForDb]).unwrap();
```

I'll award the answer to someone who can find a more elegant/ idiomatic way of doing this.

Comment: Well, the more elegant solution would be to `collect` directly into an `ArrayBase`; however `ArrayBase` does not implement `FromIterator`. Another solution would be to implement the SQL mapping for `ArrayBase<i32>` on top of `ArrayBase<Option<i32>>` or even for `Vec<i32>` maybe... as it is, the library just seems awkward to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try with either `ArrayBase::from_raw` or `ArrayBase::from_vec`. They are documented - you can either read the source code or build the docs with rustdoc.

https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/master/src/types/array.rs

Comment: @ A.B. See my question, contains my best attempt so far, which tries to use `ArrayBase::from_vec` - close but quite there yet.